# Dashboard search - change default page

Tags: unity-dash, system-settings, default, applications-lens

Every time we Ubuntu users click the dash icon, and the Dash opens, we are always greeted by the "general search" (home lens) page. Is there a way to change this? IE: I want to make the dash always open in the "Installed Applications" (application lens) section. I've looked through all the system settings, but so far, I haven't found anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the super key and the "A" key at the same time. For music lens press super key (windows key) and "M", videos is super and "V" etc.